# Selecting top X% of a column in a dataframe subject to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a `pandas` dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame(data = {"col1": [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], "col2": ["A","A","C","A","C","B","C","B","A"]})

>>> df
    col1    col2
0   9       A
1   8       A
2   7       C
3   6       A
4   5       C
5   4       B
6   3       C
7   2       B
8   1       A
```

Say, I want to select the 33% highest values in col1 (corresponding to 3 rows), but so that I have 1 in each of the values of col2 (A, B, C). In this case I want row index number 0, 2 and 5.

I can of course solve this by iterating through the rows with a for loop and keeping track of the col2 values, but is there a faster/smarter way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure how to reconcile the top 30% with the other requirement.  If you had 100 values, you cannot have the largest 30 if the all of the values of with `C` in `col2` are 0.

Comment: should be top third - sorry

Comment: I correspond 33% to 3 values/rows as there are 9 rows in all. So, starting from top since df is ordered, the first value is row 0, with col1 value 9 (the highest). This has A i col2, so the next can't be row 1, as this is also has col2=A. The second value is row 2, and the third and final is row 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get the index if length condition is for each group -

```
import math
import itertools

dict1 = df.groupby(['col2'], sort=False).groups # returns the dict with groupname and index list
index_list  =[value[:round(len(value) * 0.33)] for key,value in dict1.items()] # taking 33% from each group
flat_index_list = list(itertools.chain(*index_list)) # flatten list
print(flat_index_list) # will print [0,2,5]
```

You can take top k elements from each group to satisfy your length condition. If the length condition is for entire dataframe.

```
import math

len1 = int(len(df.index) * 0.33) #3 for 33%

no_of_groups = df.groupby('col2', as_index = False).ngroups #3 groups
k = math.ceil(len1 / no_of_groups) #how many elements to pick from each group k = 3/3 =1 here.

final_df = df.groupby('col2', as_index = False, sort=False).head(k) #will pick top k elements from each group
```

To get the random amount of data from each group specify the amount in amount list -

```
import math
import itertools

dict1 = df.groupby(['col2'], sort=False).groups # returns the dict with groupname and index list
amount = [1,0,1]
index_list  =[value[:round(len(value) * (amount[index]/len(value)))] for index,(key,value) in enumerate(dict1.items())] # taking 33% from each group
flat_index_list = list(itertools.chain(*index_list)) # flatten list
print(flat_index_list) # will print [0,5]
```

Now, to select the rows use loc function -

```
print(df.loc[flat_index_list])
```

Comment: Is there an easy extension to the case where k differs for the categories? Like I want 1 in A, 0 in B and 2 in B?

Comment: yup you just need to manipulate this line - 
index_list  =[value[:round(len(value) * 0.33)] for key,value in dict1.items()] # taking 33% from each group

Comment: here, I'm hard-coding the amount (.33% ) for all the group you can use 1 list same as the size of group and on each iteration pick the element from that list